# Creating a wrapper class to use for mocking that uses IDisposable

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a third party component that I am trying to write unit tests around. The problem is that I can't mock the object and there is no interface.

I decided to create an interface and a wrapper class calling into the code for the sake of mocking. I looked into the class definition that is generated by Visual Studio using the meta data and noticed a few things:

- The class has two constructors (one takes a parameter)
- The class inherits from `IDisposable`

My questions are:

1. Does my implementation below look right?
2. Did I handle the `IDisposable` implementation correctly in the proxy class?
3. Do I need the second constructor in the proxy class since the interface does not support constructor definitions? I use dependency injection in my code and I assume unless I tell my DI framework to use the second constructor I don't really need it but I am not sure.

The meta data looks like (slimmed down version):

```
public class PopClient : IDisposable
{
    public const int DefaultPort = 110;
    public const int DefaultSSLPort = 995;

    public PopClient();
    public PopClient(AddressFamily addressFamily);
    public bool HasTimeStamp { get; }
    public List<string> Capability();
    public void Connect(string host);
    protected override void GetServerGreeting();
}
```

Based on the meta data, my interface looks like (after removing methods/properties/access modifiers that are invalid in an interface definition):

```
public interface IPopClient : IDisposable
{
    bool HasTimeStamp { get; }
    List<string> Capability();
    void Connect(string host);
    void ConnectSSL(string host);
}
```

Based on the interface, I then created the wrapper class:

```
public class PopClientProxy : IPopClient
{
    private readonly Pop3 pop3;

    public PopClientProxy()
        this.pop3 = new Pop3();

    public PopClientProxy(AddressFamily addressFamily)
        this.pop3 = new Pop3(addressFamily);

    public bool HasTimeStamp
        get { return pop3.HasTimeStamp; }

    public List<string> Capability()
        return pop3.Capability();

    public void Connect(string host)
        pop3.Connect(host);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (pop3 != null)
            pop3.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations! You have successfully utilized the object-oriented design pattern known as the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). I think that looks perfectly good. Though, I wouldn't check `pop3` for `null` in the `Dispose()` method as it will be guaranteed to not be null by the constructors and the `readonly` field modifier:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    pop3.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I'm by no means an expert about `IDisposable`, but isn't there a risk that the thread gets aborted while the constructor runs, and the object subsequently gets disposed by the garbage collector, in which case `pop3` may be `null` ?

Comment: If your constructor aborts, the constructor will throw an exception. `pop3` will either be picked up by the garbage collector or, if it were `null`, won't matter, because the `Dispose()` won't get called because the full `PopClient` object isn't created and is a null value (the `using` statement won't call `Dispose()` on a null object).